# Integrating continuous function of two variables by one of the variables, do I get continuous function?

Tags: integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function continuous in $x$ such that $g(x) = \int_a^b f(x,y) dy$ exists for every $x$. Is $g(x)$ necessarily continuous? I am especially interested in the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us take any sequence $(x_n)_n$ converging towards $x$. Consider $f_n(y)=f(x_n,y)$. By continuity of $f$, each $f_n$ is Lebesgue integrable. Furthermore, $f_n\to f$ for $n\to \infty$. Now, $$g(x)=\int f(x,y)dy=\int \lim\limits_n f_n(y)dy=\lim\limits_n\int f_n(y)dy=\lim\limits_n g(x_n),$$ where we used the Dominated Convergence Theorem to interchange limit and integration. But what we just wrote is the sequential criterion for continuity.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. I understand that from what you said, $F(x,y)$ has to be continuous w.r.t. $y$, but I do not see why it should follow that it is continuous in $x$, too, which is what I need here. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely right! Let me suggest $f(x,y)=\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)\cdot y$ as a counterexample. If we integrate it wrt $y$ we should obtain something highly discontinuous..

Comment: I don't think that works either, as I require $f$ to be continuous in $x$.

Comment: @user2316602 Sorry for being so careless today. I edited the answer again, now hopefully giving a correct proof of this fact. If there are still errors, you may of course correct me again.

Comment: @user2316602 does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. Thank you.

Comment: This still fails. Continuity in $y$ is required, see the below counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterexample
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0&y=0\\
\frac{1}{y^2}\max\left\{y-|x-y|,0\right\}&y\neq0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$f(x,y)$ is countinuous expect for $(0,0)$. But for $0<x<1$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
g(x)&:=\int_0^1f(x,y)dy
\geq\int_{3x/4}^x\frac{1}{y^2}\left(y-|x-y|\right)dy\\
&\geq\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{x}{4}\cdot(\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{x}{4})=\frac{1}{8}
\end{align*}$$
Since $g(0)$ is obviously $0$, $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$

Comment: Nice find. Continuity in $y$ is also a requirement, as this illustrates.

Comment: @K.defaoite
In fact $f$ is continuous in $y$ (continuous in $y$ for each fixed $x$, I mean). Furthermore, as a binary function, $f$ is discontinuous only at origin. But if we require $f$ is a continuous binary function, the proposition will become a well-known one.